# How can I send an email when objects get invalidated?

Tags: plsql, plsql-developer

I have couple stored procedures and a package.

Whenever this stored procedure and package goes invalid, I need to send an email.

How can I achieve this?

Can you please give me an idea how this can be done.

Comment: what do you mean by "go invalid"?  Do you mean "they fail to execute"?

Comment: "go invalid" means when an object gets invalidated

Comment: Why send an email? You should try to fix the root cause: Why are your packages becoming invalid?

Comment: not sure,why these are getting invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of this question requires some work on your part but as a rough guide:

- get an email package.  You can roll your own using UTL_SMTP (Pre Oracle 10) or it's succesor UTL_MAIL (Oracle 10 onwards).  However this is such a basic functionality that many people have written and shared their own versions. For Oracle 11 and beyond do not forget to allocate permissions for your database to access the ports required.
- create a package to manage your errors.  Today you want to see when a package has been invalidated, tomorrow it will be something else. Plan for the future.... You would need to create a procedure with a cursor along the lines of 
  SELECT owner,
     object_type,
     object_name,
     status
  FROM   dba_objects
  WHERE  status = 'INVALID'
  ORDER BY owner, object_type, object_name;
- open the cursor, when you find something, use the email package to mail who you want
- finally, if you find a problem, fix the problem: use the handy code here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/recompiling-invalid-schema-objects.php to recompile the package

Edit: the original poster asks how to track incidents.  More information is needed such, Oracle version, what kind of incidents, how often do you want to receive notifications.

Comment: can i get an overview on how to send email notification on expiring tickets -incidents.i can handle the email part now